# Reading specific message from EventHub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am wanting to read a specific message from an EventHub.

I'm using the `EventHubConsumerClient` and the `ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync` using a partitionId, and Offset I have.

`client.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(partitionId, EventPosition.FromOffset(offset), cancellationSource.Token);`

The issue I have is, that despite the Offset and Partition ID being correct, I'm not getting the messages I expect back.

**Context**

I working on something to validate that messages are being properly processed in a distributed system.

`Source Event Hub -> Processor Function -> Destination Event Hubs.`

I read both ends (hubs) and validate messages arrive where they should, if they don't, look up the message from the Source Event Hub, (by partitionId and offset matching against a message ID).

It is the messages I'm looking up that don't appear to have message IDs or offset IDs I expect.

Comment: how do you make sure that the offset is correct? where are you getting that from? offsets between different Event Hubs can be totally different

Comment: I get the offset from the "Source" when I read the message, and when I re-send I'm re-reading the message off the source again

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the process that you're describing.   Can you elaborate on how you're capturing the offset and how you're later looking it up?   If possible, code snippets in the question would be very helpful.

Comment: Im using an Azure Function EventHub trigger, which provides it in the functionContext

Comment: The functions trigger behavior changes based on the signature used.   In batch cases, for example, the function context returns a value that represents a range of offsets.  _([src](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/src/Triggers/EventHubTriggerInput.cs#L79))_ Can you include a code snippet for the signature of your function?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

I was mistaken in my recall of the defaults for `EventPosition` and referenced docs for the wrong SDK package below.  By default, `EventPosition.FromOffset` is inclusive. *([src](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Consumer/EventPosition.cs#L82))*

The creation pattern in the question would include the event at the provided offset.  If you're not seeing the event returned, then the offset would seem to be incorrect.

**Original Answer  *(incorrect)*:**

The `EventPosition` that you're building is non-inclusive and will not include the event at that offset, but rather start at the next available event.  Using the following overload should target the event that you're looking for:

```cs
EventPosition.FromOffset(offset, true)
```

It looks as if the summary in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventposition.fromoffset?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't do a great job of calling attention to the default; I'll take a follow-up to make that more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I looks like my offsets *are* wrong - they come in a batch, and I'm using the `BindingContext.BindingData["OffSetArray"]` - Im going to write a POC app to check the data.

Comment: On further investigation - the code was right, the offsets were wrong.

Using the azure libs, and batches of more than one - the metadata was providing completely the wrong offsets. An upgrade (to preview) resolved this :/

Comment: Glad that you were able to track it down.  If possible, I'd recommend reading position metadata direct from `EventData` over the function context.    I'm not a fan of the implicit changes to behavior for the context, personally.

Comment: I'd love to (and did) but the new .net 6 isolated process stuff only seems to work if you take `string events[]` as a param, rather than  `EventData[] events`.. I KNOW.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the incorrect offsets being provided from the AZ Function binding metadata.

Using a batch of one - correct.

Using a batch of more than one, completely wrong offsets, sequences etc.

Updated the eventhubs package (preview..) and it works fine :/